# Receiver type ‘X’ for instance message is a forward declaration CGPOINT, IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I have seen similar questions for same error.After refactoring code to Arc I get  **Receiver type ‘CGPointObject’ for instance message is a forward declaration** error . And it is recommended that move @class method to .h file and #import .h file of declaration, and use { wisely.

I did all of recommendations but I still get error.

CCParallaxNode-Extras.h

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@class CGPointObject;

@interface CCParallaxNode (Extras)

-(void) incrementOffset:(CGPoint)offset forChild:(CCNode*)node;

@end
```

CCParallaxNode-Extras.m

```
    #import "CCParallaxNode-Extras.h"
    #import "CCParallaxNode.h"


    @implementation CCParallaxNode(Extras)


    -(void) incrementOffset:(CGPoint)offset forChild:(CCNode*)node 
    {

        for( unsigned int i=0;i < parallaxArray_->num;i++) {
            CGPointObject *point = parallaxArray_->arr[i];
            if( [[point child] isEqual:node] ) {
                [point setOffset:ccpAdd([point offset], offset)];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

@end
```

Definition of class:CCParallaxNode.m

```
#import "CCParallaxNode.h"
#import "Support/CGPointExtension.h"
#import "Support/ccCArray.h"

@interface CGPointObject : NSObject
{
    CGPoint ratio_;
    CGPoint offset_;
    CCNode *child_; // weak ref
}
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) CGPoint ratio;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) CGPoint offset;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite,assign) CCNode *child;
+(id) pointWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point offset:(CGPoint)offset;
-(id) initWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point offset:(CGPoint)offset;
@end
@implementation CGPointObject
@synthesize ratio = ratio_;
@synthesize offset = offset_;
@synthesize child=child_;

+(id) pointWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)ratio offset:(CGPoint)offset
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithCGPoint:ratio offset:offset] autorelease];
}
-(id) initWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)ratio offset:(CGPoint)offset
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        ratio_ = ratio;
        offset_ = offset;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

How can I solve above problem ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You include `#import "CCParallaxNode.h"` in `CCParallaxNode-Extras.m` like you should but according to `CCParallaxNode.m` you are defining both the `@interface` and the `@implementation`. You need to move the `@interface` section out of `CCParallaxNode.m` and into the header file.

CCParallaxNode.h

```
//Add necessary includes ...

@interface CGPointObject : NSObject
{
    CGPoint ratio_;
    CGPoint offset_;
    CCNode *child_; // weak ref
}
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) CGPoint ratio;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) CGPoint offset;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite,assign) CCNode *child;
+(id) pointWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point offset:(CGPoint)offset;
-(id) initWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point offset:(CGPoint)offset;
@end
```